# Stuck with Titanium Studio proper installation

Tags: android, sdk, path, titanium

I have a fresh titanium installation..

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed it properly, except the Android SDK path. I have been googling for a while now, but with no success.

I downloaded the android sdk, extracted in a folder 'application' , did the sdk installation. (here is is showing the path)[image: img]

Now, when I am trying to configure the androdid path by providing the same path [image: here], After the configuration finishes, I am restarting the Studio but still getting the same issue. I am not sure what could be the soluion here, because I've been trying different different solutions for a while. All the answers I am following are quite OLD though.

Also getting the

> "Problem building the workspace issue"

Please help

Comment: seems like an Issue with Permissions.have you installed Titanium with root user permissions?

Comment: Probably issue was Java 1.7. I uninstalled that and installed 1.6 back and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have fixed it myself. Issue was java 1.7. Uninstalling 1.7 and installing 1.6 has solved the SDK problem.